# $z\in\mathfrak R$ iff for every $a\in A$ there is $w$ for which $z+w=zaw=waz$.

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

In his BAII, Jacobson gives the following exercise (Exercise 3 in §4.2 of *Basic Algebra II*), which he attributes to McCrimmon.

> Let $A$ be an (associative) ring with unity. Let $\mathfrak{R}\left(A\right)$ denote the Jacobson radical of $A$.
>
> Show that $z\in\mathfrak R(A)$ iff for each $a\in A$ there exists $w\in A$ such that $z+w=zaw=waz$.

I have found [this](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869371901396/1-s2.0-0021869371901396-main.pdf?_tid=b0e4d764-0c8c-11e4-9e55-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1405476093_bb12d0f9d779df942c2771e10383f18b) reference which is authored by McCrimmon and says "Communicated by Nathan Jacobson", but honestly, I cannot make much out of it (for example, I don't know what an homotope of an (alternative?) algebra is).

I have tried some algebraic manipulations using that whenver $z$ is in the radical, every element of $Az$ is left quasi-invertible and every element of $zA$ is right quasi invertible: suppose $(1-w)(1-az)=1$ and $(1-za)(1-w')=1$ that is $$\begin{eqnarray}\tag 1 w+az=waz\\ \tag 2 w'+za=zaw'\end{eqnarray}$$

Multiplying the first on the right by $aw'$ and the second on the left by $wa$ and subtracting gives $azaw'=waza$ and multiplication of the first ones by $a$ to the left and to the right resp gives $waza=wa+aza$ and $azaw'=aw'+aza$ so cancelling gives $wa=aw'$. Then we get $zw=w'z$ by the same token. This gives finally that $w+az=waz$ can be turned into $w+az=azw$, so $(1-az)(1-w)=1$ too. The same with the other. This proves that $1-az$ and $1-za$ are both q.i. Can anyone help further?

Comment: Is this question from either Basic Algebra I or II?

Comment: @BenWest It is from BAII, didn't I say that...? Ooops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose first that $z \in A$ is such that for all $a\in A$, there is $w \in A$ satisfying $z+w=zaw=waz$.

Then from $z+w=waz$ you can get $$z+w-waz=0\\ z+w(1-az)=0\\ az+aw(1-az)=0\\
1-az-aw(1-az)=1\\(1-aw)(1-az)=1
$$

This shows $1-az$ is left-invertible for any $a$. Similarly, $z+w=zaw$ shows that $1-az$ is right-invertible for any $a$. Hence, $1-az$ is invertible for any $a$, so $z$ is in the radical.

Supposing now that $z$ is in the radical and $a\in A$, we seek a $w \in A$ such that $z+w=zaw=waz$. Solving $z+w=zaw$ for $w$ you get $$w-zaw=-z\\(1-za)w=-z\\w=-(1-za)^{-1}z$$. The inverse exists, of course, since $za$ is (left and right) quasiregular.

From our computation above, we already know $z+w=zaw$, so all that's left is to confirm that $zaw=waz=z+w$.

We have $$waz=-(1-za)^{-1}zaz\\=-(1-za)^{-1}z+(1-za)^{-1}z-(1-za)^{-1}zaz\\
=-(1-za)^{-1}z+(1-za)^{-1}(1-za)z\\=-(1-za)^{-1}z+z=w+z$$